# Is there a way to generate JSON template to create this output?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, templates, mustache, amazon-kinesis

I have an output I am trying to recreate via a JSON template in kinesis data generator. I am having trouble creating the "AbsoluteDate" variable to generate a random date within a range. Same thing with AbsoluteTime; I want it to generate a random time of day. Here's what I have so far:

```
[
{
    "Version": "2019-08-26",
    "AWSAccountId": "{{random.number(
        {
            "min": 1234567890,
            "max": 2345678901
}
)}}",
    "InstanceId": "{{random.number(
        {
            "min": 5678901234,
            "max": 6789012345
}
)}}",

    "ContactId": "74982038-f839-4ace-8b6f-3a31f788d8ae",
    "CustomerName": "{{name.firstName}} {{name.lastName}}", 
    "Content": {{random.number(
        {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 4
}
)}},
    "AbsoluteDate": "{{date.between(
        {
            "from": 01-01-01
            "to": 01-01-21
}
)}}",
    "AbsoluteTime":
```

Everything works upto the AbosluteDate. Any tips?

For reference, here's the output I am trying to generate:

```
"Version": "2019-08-26",
    "AWSAccountID": "77-9197985",
    "InstanceId": "66-082-8615",
    "ContactId": "74982038-f839-4ace-8b6f-3a31f788d8ae",
    "Customer Name": "Clarey Oris",
    "Content": 4,
    "AbsoluteTime": "17:03:28.000",
    "AbsoluteDate": "2020-09-06"
```